# Create an ImmutableMap using Java 8

Tags: java, java-stream, guava, collectors

How can the following method be written using Java Stream API?

```
public Map<String, String> getMap() {
    Map<String, String> mapB = new HashMap<>();
    
    for (String parameterKey : listOfKeys) {
        String parameterValue = mapA.get(parameterKey);
        
        mapB.put(parameterKey, Objects.requireNonNullElse(parameterValue, ""));
    }
    return ImmutableMap.copyOf(mapB);
}
```

I tried something like this:

```
return listOfKeys.stream()
    .map(firstMap::get)
    .collect( ? )
```

But I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: Also, you can pass an existing map to [`Map.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#copyOf(java.util.Map))

Answer (score 2):

## Guava

If you need Guava's `ImmutableMap`, you can make use of the `Collector` returned by [`ImmutableMap.toImmutableMap()`](https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#toImmutableMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) available since Guava's version `21.0`.

***Note:*** the minimum JDK version required by the Guava 21.0 release is **Java 8** ([see](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release21#user-content-java-8)), hence below is a valid Java 8 compliant solution.

```
public Map<String, String> getMap() {
    
    return listOfKeys.stream()
        .collect(ImmutableMap.toImmutableMap(
            Function.identity(),               // keyMapper - generating keys
            str -> mapA.getOrDefault(str, ""), // valueMapper - generating values
            (left, right) -> left              // mergeFunction - resolving duplicates
        ));
}
```

In case if you're using Guava's version earlier than `21.0`, then you can generate the resulting map using standard JDK collector [`toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) and wrap it with an `ImmutableMap` by the means of [`collectingAndThen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.Function)).

This approach would be cleaner, cramming the stream as an argument of the `copyOf()` method as suggested in another answer:

```
public Map<String, String> getMap() {
    
    return istOfKeys.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.toMap(
                Function.identity(),               // keyMapper - generating keys
                str -> mapA.getOrDefault(str, ""), // valueMapper - generating values
                (left, right) -> right),           // mergeFunction - resolving duplicates
            ImmutableMap::copyOf
        ));
}
```

**Note:**

- If all elements contained in `listOfKeys` are guaranteed to be unique, then you can remove `mergeFunction` (*the third argument of the collector*).
- I've replaced `Objects.requireNonNullElse()` with `Map.getOrDefault()` which would guard against the cases when a *key* is not present in the `mapA`. If you also want you protect against situations when the *value* associated with the *key* is `null`, then replace it with `requireNonNullElse()`. But you need to be aware that it's a sign of a faulty design if `null` values are being stored in the map because they have some special meaning in your business logic (and therefore you can't get rid of them).

## Standard JDK

Otherwise, you can use collector [`Collectors.toUnmodifiableMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toUnmodifiableMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function))

It internally uses a combination of collectors `toMap()`, accumulates stream data into a map, and `collectingAndThen()`) which performs the final transformation into a so-called [*unmodifiable map*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#unmodifiable) created via `Map.ofEntries()`.

```
public Map<String, String> getMap() {

    return listOfKeys.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableMap(
            Function.identity(),               // keyMapper - generating keys
            str -> mapA.getOrDefault(str, ""), // valueMapper - generating values
            (left, right) -> left              // mergeFunction - resolving duplicates
        ));
}
```